# Trim Sheet Name while read_excel in Pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I am trying to read excel with multiple sheets. I am able to read most of the files and their sheet names quiet correctly. However, some sheet names have a blank trailing space either before or after.

```py
# I know the sheet name    
party_str="Party Details"

# Reading that Sheet name
sheets['df_Party'] = pd.read_excel(open(data_file,'rb'), party_str)
```

```py
**Error:**

XLRDError: No sheet named <'Party Details'>
```

**Extra space after Details**

[image: extra space after Details]

**Is there any pythonic way to handle this?**

Answer (score 0):

Use `xlrd` to get your sheet names of the file if that's convenient for you:

```
import xlrd
xls = xlrd.open_workbook('your_xlsx_file.xlsx')
print(xls.sheet_names())
```

Comment: no, i am looking for more pythonic : ```pd.read_excel(open(data_file,'rb'), sheetname=party_str.strip())```

Comment: @SaqibMujtaba well there is no `pythonic` way as you say to do this. If you don't get the sheet names with one or another way then its `guessing`. Doing it your way could only be done by adding or removing spaces till you find the correct one.

Comment: hmm. Ok mate. I got it! Thanks !!